# Get localized date without year in android

Tags: java, android, date

I need to omit the year in the localized date. The localized DateFormat containing the year can be obtained by DateFormat.getDateInstance()

I cannot use `SimpleDateFormat` directly as I will have to assume the relative orderings. I was wondering if there is a way to determine the localized orderings of the parts, or get the format string itself, so that I can remove the `y's` from it and construct a SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: hard to parse a date without knowing the exact format. You can have a list of possible formats and parse through them with the input to get a successful parse, and use that as the format.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse dates. I'm trying to format dates from milliseconds

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do now: try this: int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR;
  String monthAndDayWithoutYear = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, new Date(millisecs), flags);

Comment: This is what I needed and it works. The second argument takes millis directly.

Comment: Ok but as I stated above, the second argument should be millis directly and not a Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FORMAT_SHOW_DATE` or `FORMAT_NO_YEAR` to remove year from a date regardless of its locale:

```
 int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR; 
 String monthAndDayWithoutYear = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, millisecs, flags);
```